# c++ and php HEX

Tags: php, c++, linux

i this code in c++ which converts integer to HEX, but the output in php is different

**C++:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  string str1("100106014020");
  int i;

  i = atoi(str1.c_str());
  printf ("HEX value is %X", i);

  return 0;
}

output:
HEX value is 4EC88D44
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$num = '100106014020';
$nnum = (int)$num;
echo printf ("%X",$nnum);
?>
```

output: 
174EC88D4410

how can i get the same HEX value in php as the one in c++?

Comment: You should consider `atoi` a programming error.

Comment: `100106014020` is bigger than int's max-size

Comment: and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/ says it's not specified what happens in that case.

Comment: You should be more interested in getting the *right* answer in both languages.

Comment: The right answer: `174EC88D44`. PHP has an extra `10`. How come?

Answer (score 3):

It is simply a programming error to use `atoi`, since you cannot know whether the conversion suc­cee­ded or not. The correct function to use is [`strtol`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll) (or `strtoll`). The corrected program should look like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cerrno>

int main()
{
    const char * const str1 = "100106014020";
    char * e;
    long i = std::strtol(str1, &e, 0);

    if (e != 0)
    {
        std::printf("Conversion error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    else
    {
        std::printf("Conversion succeeded, value = 0x%lX\n", i);
    }
}
```

For me this says:

```
Conversion error: Numerical result out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overflowing the capacity of the integer.  Use a long instead.

Comment: You need to use atol then;)  atoi returns ints. atol returns longs.

Comment: @RyanGuthrie: how long is your long?

Comment: @krisdigitx: That's idiotic. The C++ code is horribly broken, and we surely don't need even *more* terrible PHP code!

Comment: @krisdigitx why do you want the wrong answer in PHP? You might as well print the number `42` in both.